# What language is this HTML include snippet?

Tags: html, templates, tags

I have inherited some .html files with include tags like the following:

```
[% INCLUDE '/path/to/footer.html' %]
```

I don't recognize this bracket-and-percent-sign tag. Can anyone identify it for me?

Comment: Take a look at some of these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system

Answer (score 1):

The file you're looking at is almost certainly using [`Template::Toolkit`](http://search.cpan.org/~abw/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Toolkit.pod) syntax. This specific bit of syntax is documented in [`Template::Manual::Directives`](http://search.cpan.org/~abw/Template-Toolkit/lib/Template/Manual/Directives.pod#INCLUDE).

Answer (score 0):

It is basically SAS syntax please refer [Sas Syntax](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#win-cmd-include.htm)

Comment: SAS seems very unlikely to be used to generate HTML. At least, I hope so. :P

Comment: Nothing wrong with using SAS to generate HTML.  However this is certainly not SAS syntax...

Answer (score 0):

I poked around and found that my web server was using mod-perl, and that this [Template library](http://perl.apache.org/docs/tutorials/tmpl/comparison/comparison.html#HTML__Template) was being used to process the HTML file in question.